# char array to String at runtime?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, arduino

I have trouble to copy a char array into a `String`. The following line works fine:

```
String packetBufferString(packetBuffer);
```

But obviously I can do this only once, since `packetBufferString` has to be global and cannot be declared again. The problem is that `packetBuffer` changes at runtime but I can't update `packetBufferString`.

The char array is set up with

```
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];
```

lg, couka

Comment: This code looks like a mix of Java and C++. Did you mean std::string? It's also not clear what is being asked / what the problem is.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan They mean [`arduino String`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject).

Comment: Avoid using strings if you can on the arduino.

Comment: I can't since I have to parse incoming UDP-packets.

Answer (score 0):

If `String` is `std::string` then you can write

```
std::string packetBufferString(packetBuffer);

//

packetBufferString.assign(packetBuffer);
```

or

```
std::string packetBufferString(packetBuffer);

//

packetBufferString  = packetBuffer;
```

provided that `packetBuffer` is zero-terminated. Otherwise you can do the same (that is assigning) but using initial and ending iterators for `packetBuffer`